# Directory checking in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script shell that takes two arguments as directory names, and determines if Directory 1 contains Directory 2 or vice versa. And also if there is no relationship between them.

I know the command to check if a directory exists is find -type d, however i was a bit confused as how to check and parse then names. I know i would need if-else loops, just not sure how to check for the conditions?

Comment: The check if a directory exists would be `if [[ -d dirname ]]`. What you wrote (`find -type d`) is *finding all items of type "directory"*, and you would still have to check the result.

Comment: How would I check if one directory contains another?

Comment: Do you consider only parsing the names, or want to also consider the symbolic links?   If partial path contains a symbolic link, it will be hard.  (Yet should still be possible.)

Comment: Only parsing the names. I dont think I need to worry about symbolic links.

Comment: I am still unclear what, exactly, your requirement actually is, so I am just tossing hints in here. With `readlink -e`, you can turn relative paths and / or paths containing symlinks into *full* paths containing *no* symlinks (i.e., "real" paths). At that point, to check if one directory is contained in the other, all you need is to check if the shorter string is a left-bound substring of the longer...

Answer (score 3):

`find` won't be needed.
Something similar to this (but not guaranteeing directory name with spaces or some special characters.):

```
if [ "$dir1" == "$dir2" ]; then
   echo "$dir1 == $dir2";
   exit;
fi
if grep -E -q "^$dir2" <<< $dir1; then
   echo "$dir1 is contained by $dir2."
   exit
fi
if grep -E -q  "^$dir1" <<< $dir2; then
   echo "$dir2 is contained by $dir1.";
fi
```

However, this does not deal with symbolic links.  For example,  `sym1 -> /usr/local/bin` and `sym2 -> /usr/local`, apparently, `sym2` contains `sym1`.

In addition, this does not deal with strange looking directory names, like `/usr/local/./bin`, which is the same as `/usr/local/bin`, or even `/usr/local/../bin`, which is the same as `/usr/bin`

--- Update ---
DevSolar metioned that `readlink -e` can be used to resolve the symbolic link.  In my test, it also resolves the strange looking directory names like those with `.` and `..`.  Thanks to DevSolar.

Comment: Don't use `grep` like this. Instead, use `grep` with the `-q` switch, as an argument to the `if`: `if grep -E -q "^$dir1" <<< "$dir2"; then`. Now your whole method is flawed if the directory name contains special characters that will be interpreted as regex (e.g., `.`, `?`, `(`, etc.). I would certainly not recommend that. In fact, there are better ways to check for substring without external tools: `if [[ $dir1 = "$dir2"* ]]; then` is much much better.

Comment: Great to know `-q` option for `grep`.   And yes, I know `if grep`  well, and I normally use that. I was just been stereotyped by other's `$?` answer.  :-)  I will edit the answer right now.

Comment: @gniourf_gnirourf As for your `if [[ $dir1 = "$dir2"* ]]`, I believe it's a better answer, and you should post it as a new answer.  I won't change mine.

Comment: @gniourf_gnirourf  and `<<<` here string is good.  I never know that.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
if [ -d $1 ];then
    a=`find $1 -type d -name $2`
    if [ $a ];then
        echo "$1 has $2"
    else
        echo "$1 does NOT has $2"
    fi
fi

if [ -d $2 ];then
    b=`find $2 -type d -name $1`
    if [ $b ];then
        echo "$2 has $1"
    else
        echo "$2 does NOT has $1"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick I think,

```
find -name directory1 |grep directory2
```

or vice-versa, then use

```
echo $?
```

it will give `0` for success and `1` for failure.